# How to make pod install ignore linked lib internal node_modules in react native?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-cli

I'm writing an internal UI library here.

I'm using [react-native-builder-bob](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob) and it works great, I can test my components in the `example` folder/app and focus on the library development, but when I link the lib into `my-app` (`yarn link && cd ../my-app/ && yarn link my-lib`) and run a pod install (`cd ios && pod install`), the dependencies from the `example` app end up in `my-app` `podfile.lock` like this:

```
  EXSplashScreen:
    :path: "../node_modules/my-library/example/node_modules/expo-splash-screen/ios"
```

I'm not ok with it ending up as a direct dependency. And I'm definitely not OK with it breaking my app on launch (my app doesn't use expo) because I don't even invoque any of expo stuff.

So, how can I make sure that I can develop and test things in both projects (`example` and `my-app`) without one interfering into each other?

I know I can:

1. delete example node modules when writing my-app code: but I don't want to do that.
2. pack the lib with `yarn pack`, extract the tar contents and link that instead (it doesn't include the example folder)... but it's somehow weird
3. make the `Podfile` [RN script](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/cddb0c3fb06ef949ea689221c6167147af40e37f/packages/platform-ios/native_modules.rb) ignore the example folder.. but I don't know how to do it, and will it work for android?

Edit:
About the option 3, it seems that the script that includes sub folders is the `react-native-unimodules` `cocoapods.rb` one, it fetches all packages that have `unimodules.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a direct dependency. Unfortunately `npm link`/`yarn link` doesn't have the same behavior as a published package. It's also intended for development and not for consuming the package in an app.

To have the proper behavior, you need to publish the package to a registry and consume it from there. The example isn't uploaded when publishing.

To test this behavior locally you can:

- Use something like https://verdaccio.org/ for a local NPM server
- Run `npm pack` to create a `tgz` package that you can install with `yarn install /path/to/file`

Comment: oh, local verdaccio seems to be a great idea!

Comment: by the way: "It's also intended for development and not for consuming the package in an app." that's exactly what I wanted, but because the community script end up scanning the linked example app folder this (link) does work properly for development